# changes two one Array always changing another one as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

For a project I need to import an Excel File, change the data to JSON, and reformat it in different ways to be readable for my application. One step involves splitting one line of the Excel into two different arrays which have to be changed individually.

But whatever I'm doing wrong - any changes to one of the Arrays changes not only the other array accordingly, but also my original data.

```js
let data = [{
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2
}, {
  value1: 3,
  value2: 4
}]
let temp1 = [];
let temp2 = [];
for (let x of data) {
  temp1.push(x); //pushing x in array 1
  temp2.push(x); //pushing x as well in array 2
}
for (let x of temp1) {
  x.type = 'typeA'
}
for (let x of temp2) {
  x.type = 'typeB'
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp2));
//all three give the same result.
```

Does anybody know where my code went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript arrays is referenced based - so you can kind of look at it as array 1 and array 2 containing references to the same value. Changing the value in one array will change it in the other because they are the same underlying thing anyway.

What you're really looking for is how to deep clone values. Here's an example of how you can get around that limitation.

```js
let data = [{
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2
}, {
  value1: 3,
  value2: 4
}]
let temp1 = [];
for (let x of data) {
  temp1.push(x); //pushing x in array 1
}
  
// This is one of the "workaround ways" of constructing
// an array of fresh values (otherwise known as deep cloning).
// this doesn't work in cases where you might have cyclic javascript
// objects or functions, but works if you're dealing with JSON values.
let temp2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp1));

for (let x of temp1) {
  x.type = 'typeA'
}
for (let x of temp2) {
  x.type = 'typeB'
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp2));
//all three give the same result.
```

Since you actually know that your data is a list of objects this could work. In practice, you might want to use something more robust ... like lodash's cloneDeep: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep

Answer (score 1):

data is the only object defined here, you are just making references and pushing the data to other arrays,

Look at how these snippets work too

```js
var x = {};
var y = x;
y.age = 10;
console.log("x is :",x);
//{age:10;}
var a = [];
var b = a;
b.push(10);
console.log("a is :",a);
//[10]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are `looping the data objects` and assigning each of its value to temp values, so the `memory location` of those will be the `same as of data`.

So, make `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` to change the memory location and loop it,

Change,

```
for (let x of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))) {
  temp1.push(x); //pushing x in array 1
  temp2.push(x); //pushing x as well in array 2
}
```

```js
let data = [{
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2
}, {
  value1: 3,
  value2: 4
}]
let temp1 = [];
let temp2 = [];
for (let x of JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))) {
  temp1.push(x); //pushing x in array 1
  temp2.push(x); //pushing x as well in array 2
}
temp1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp1))
for (let x of temp1) {
  x.type = 'typeA'
}
temp2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp2))
for (let y of temp2) {
  y.type = 'typeB'
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp2));
//all three give the same result.
```

**Please run the above snippet**

Comment: @Torf, but you dont need your original array to be changed right?,  your original array do not need the `type` values. check my answer.

Comment: you need your original array to get type values?

Comment: That's right. My original data does not need any changes (at this point - it has been changed before). Those types are only for the derived arrays.

Comment: @Torf, so the accepted answer also changed the data array and added type to it.

Comment: Yes, but that does not matter at this point. I do not need the data array any more as from there on I work with `temp1` & `temp2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `data`, `temp1`, and `temp2` are three different arrays, but the items in `temp1` and `temp2` are just references to the items in the `data` array, so they're all just refering to the same objects. Because of this, changing the objects in one array will affect the others arrays.

What you could do is instead of running `temp1.push(x)` and `temp2.push(x)`, you `push` a copy of the `x` object instead. This could be done like so:

```
temp1.push(Object.assign({}, x));
temp2.push(Object.assign({}, x));
```

This way, the items contained in your three arrays will be unique objects,  and not just references to the same objects.